# What can we say about the function $f(x,k) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} x^{(n^{2k})}$?

Tags: number-theory, summation

I'm trying to explore a function defined as
$$f(x,k) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} x^{(n^{2k})}$$
It almost looks like a theta function, but not quite.
I was just wondering if anyone had any information, or something to point me towards for further reading.